# Ошибка CS0029 в коде для UNITY

Tags: c#

Этот код был взят из книги по C# и Unity, но только вот что-то он не компилируется в юнити. Но я понять не могу это в книге код неправильный, или это я. Ошибка на линии 24,28
Полный текст ошибки:
Assets\Scripts\ApplePicker.cs(24,28): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'UnityEngine.GameObject' to 'UnityEngine.GameObject[]'
**РАБОЧИЙ КОД:**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Apple : MonoBehaviour {
    [Header("Set in Inspector")]
    public static float bottomY = -20f;
    
    void Update() {
        if (transform.position.y < bottomY) {
            Destroy (this.gameObject);
            
            ApplePicker apScript = Camera.main.GetComponent<ApplePicker>();
            apScript.AppleDestroyed();
        }
    }
}
```

**НЕ РАБОЧИЙ КОД**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ApplePicker : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Set in Inspector")]
    public GameObject basketPrefab;
    public int numBaskets = 3;
    public float basketBottomY = -14f;
    public float basketSpacingY = 2f;
    
    void Start()
    {
    for (int i = 0; i<numBaskets; i++) {
        GameObject tBasketGO = Instantiate<GameObject>(basketPrefab);
        Vector3 pos = Vector3.zero;
        pos.y = basketBottomY + (basketSpacingY * i);
        tBasketGO.transform.position = pos;
        }    
    }
    
    public void AppleDestroyed() {
        GameObject[] tAppleArray=GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Apple");
        foreach (GameObject tGO in tAppleArray) {
            Destroy(tGO);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Текст ошибки? Строка с ошибкой?

Comment: @tym32167 Добавил

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего в учебнике написано не так:

> GameObject[] tAppleArray=GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Apple");

А так:

> GameObject[] tAppleArray=GameObject.FindGameObject**s**WithTag("Apple");

Comment: Хотя непонятно, функция `FindGameObjectWithTag` вообще не ищется в доках по юнити. Либо это какое-то легаси, уже не описанное в документации, но ещё работающее, либо это тоже функция из книжки, используемая автором вопроса, но не приведённая в коде.

Comment: Действительно в документации её нет, но в UnityEngine.GameObject она есть, только что проверил.

Comment: @CrazyElf такой функции нету, по этому она и не ищется. Ошибкой была моя простая рассеянность, я не увидел s в `...ObjectsWithTag` и написал без, по этому ничего и не компилировалось

Comment: Она есть, и она возвращает первый найденный объект с заданным тегом.

Comment: @Артём Если бы такой функции не было, ошибка была бы другая. У вас ошибка приведения результата работы функции к нужному типу, а не ошибка отсутствия такой функции.